# How to keep controller parameter populated when browser is refreshed in MVC?

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, controller, refresh

I would like to keep the parameters of my controller populated to what was previously sent when the browser is refreshed.

I would like the page to refresh with the same information that was displayed instead of throwing a null. The error that is thrown when browser is refreshed: "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter..."

Comment: The is a contatiner call TempData that can hold the params for two requests. https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TempData](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc) to hold params for two calls:

```
public ActionResult FirstCall()
{
    TempData["Param1"] = "Param1";
    return View();
}

public ActionResult SecondCall()
{ 
    ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
    model.param1 = TempData["Param1"];
    return View();
}
```